# jQuery, click to add class to offset 49px

Tags: jquery, offset, scrollto

On my one page website, I am using the Scroll To functionality that scrolls to different parts of the website.

There is a fixed navigation that offsets by 49px so it can land on the section perfectly.

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($(this.hash).offset().top - 49)}, 1800,
        function() {}
    );
    return false;
});
```

But I have a blog on the website. So what I want to happen is when I click on the fixed navigation from the blog it will offset the navigation by 49px, currently it doesnt reconise the offset. I have tried this but doesnt work.

```
$('nav a.secondary-link').click(function(event) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($(this.hash).offset().top - 49)}, 1800,
        function() {}
    );
    return false;
});
```

You can see my workings here: If you view the news page first you can notice that the section doesn't recognise the 49px offset.

http://aspe.fishtankcreative.co.uk/newcastle-falcons/blog/falcons-to-support-primary-school-sport-with-new-initiative.php

http://aspe.fishtankcreative.co.uk/newcastle-falcons/

Please help. Thanks

Comment: In place of what, sorry still learning javaScript / jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because in the blog post, the links, are ACTUAL links, meaning they change page, causing a complete request to the server and a reload of all Javascript. The click event is gone by the time the next page is up, which is where you want to scroll. Luckily we get a hash with us, which gives us a hook we can use to animate afterwards.

This should do it for you :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idOfSection = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var $sectionToScrollTo = $('#'+idOfSection);
    if($sectionToScrollTo.length > 0){
        var offset = $sectionToScrollTo.offset().top-49; 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offset },1800);
    }
});
```

If you want it to scroll from the top, add: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0},0);` as the first thing in the if statement.

---

**To improve further**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sectionId = window.location.hash;
    scrollToSection(sectionId);

    $('body').on('click', 'nav a', function(){
        var secId = this.hash;
        scrollToSection(secId);
    }
});

function scrollToSection(sectionId){
    var $sectionToScrollTo = $(sectionId);
    if($sectionToScrollTo.length > 0){
        var offset = $sectionToScrollTo.offset().top-49; 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offset },1800);
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't tested the second code example.

Comment: Yes this worked when coming from an external page. But using the navigation on the main page, its doesn't scroll nor does it offset by 49px

Comment: I've had to add this to make it work on the main page: `$('nav a').click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($(this.hash).offset().top - 49)}, 1800,
                function() {}
            );
            return false;
        });`

Comment: @BarryCorrigan I made an update to my answer. Also if you found it helpful please upvote the answer, so I get a warm fuzzy feeling inside hehe.